# Running a Common Lisp function from a Terminal command prompt

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm having some difficulty finding an answer to this, so maybe it isn't possible. I'd like the flexibility of being able to load/compile a lisp file from a command line, i.e. not inside emacs, and then also run one of the lisp functions in that file also from the command line. This is no doubt implementation specific feature, so any pointers on an implementation that offers this (or perhaps it is fairly standard, I don't know). I'm using SBCL and like it, so it would be great if that could do this.

Also I'm using Mac OSX and Terminal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The SBCL manual describes three useful options

> #### [3.3.1 Runtime Options](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Runtime-Options)
>
> `--noinform`
>   Suppress the printing of any banner or other
>   informational message at startup. This makes it easier to write Lisp
>   programs which work cleanly in Unix pipelines. See also the `--noprint`
>   and `--disable-debugger` options.

> #### [3.3.2 Toplevel Options](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Toplevel-Options)
>
> `--eval command`
>   After executing any initialization file, but before starting the read-eval-print loop on standard input, read and evaluate
>   the command given. More than one `--eval` option can be used, and all
>   will be read and executed, in the order they appear on the command
>   line.
>
> `--load filename`
>   This is equivalent to `--eval '(load "filename")'`. The special syntax is intended to reduce quoting headaches when invoking
>   SBCL from shell scripts.

Given a file `test.lisp` with contents

```lisp
(defun hello-world ()
  (print 'hello-world)
  (terpri))
```

we can do this with SBCL:

```
$ sbcl --noinform --load test.lisp --eval '(progn (hello-world) (sb-ext:quit))'

HELLO-WORLD
```

The `(progn ... (sb-ext:quit))` makes sure that the program ends after executing `(hello-world)`.  Otherwise you get dropped into the SBCL prompt.  Since code is compiled automatically in SBCL, the function that you're running is already compiled by the time `(hello-world)` is run.   If you've compiled the file in advance, you can pass the compiled file to `--load`.  E.g.,

```
$ sbcl --noinform --load test.fasl --eval '(hello-world)'

HELLO-WORLD
```

In fact,given the equivalence of `--load` to `--eval (load "filename")`, you can just use the base of the file name, and if there's a compiled version, then SBCL should load that, and if there's not, then SBCL will load the source file and you'll get compiled code that way.  E.g., in the following, we use just `--load test`:

```
$ sbcl --noinform --load test --eval '(hello-world)'

HELLO-WORLD
```

Answer (score 5):

The following is a paste from the [first google result](http://mwolson.org/notes/CommonLispBeginnersGuide.html):

> CLISP
>
> If you're using the CLISP Common Lisp environment, the following applies.
>
> To compile a program named test.lisp program into a bytecode file named test.fas, do the following.
>
> clisp -c test.lisp
>
> If you want less output to be shown, do the following instead.
>
> clisp -q -c test.lisp
>
> To run the compiled (or even uncompiled, if you skip the above step) Lisp file, do the following, assuming that your entry function is named main. Normally the result of the main function is shown when it's done, but the (quit) command prevents that. The -on-error abort option prevents clisp from dropping into a debugging prompt, and exits instead when there is an error.
>
> clisp -q -q -on-error abort -x '(progn (load "test") (main) (quit))'

I just tested it on my arch linux terminal and you can do the following:

`$ clisp myprogram.lisp`

This will run the program right in the terminal. If you want to compile it to run later, see the above bit.

Comment: interesting, thanks. I didn't find anything as clear for SBCL, which I'd prefer to use over Clisp for performance reasons.

Comment: @OpenLearner, perhaps `sbcl --eval '(compile-file "filename")'`. At least, its [manual](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Command-Line-Options) says that `--load filename` does the equivalent of `--eval '(load "filename")'`.

Comment: Well, I tried looking for an answer and the closest I got for you is this: ` $ sbcl --script filename.lisp` This still prints a big debugger message though, I couldn't get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

As other people have shown, pretty much all implementations have some of running Lisp code via the terminal. There are also some wrappers that provide a common interface to many implementations: [CIM](https://github.com/KeenS/CIM) and [cl-launch](http://cliki.net/cl-launch).

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to integrate `sbcl` Common-Lisp into R through knitr.
Here are few tests on how to send a request for evaluation to `sbcl` and then return it to R. This works for sending forms, not a file. From the terminal:

`sbcl --noinform --eval '(progn (print (* 2 3 4 5)) (sb-ext:quit))'`
;; 120

`sbcl --noinform --eval '(progn (print (* 2 3 4 5)) (sb-ext:quit))'`
;; HELLO-WORLD

`sbcl --noinform --eval "(progn (dotimes (i 5) (print i)) (sb-ext:quit))"`
;; 0
;; 1
;; 2
;; 3
;; 4